# ARKit plane with real world object above it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

Thanks in advance for reading my question. I am really new to ARKit and have followed several tutorials which showed me how to use plane detection and using different textures for the planes. The feature is really amazing but here is my question. Would it be possible for the player to place the plane all over the desired area first and then interact with the new `ground`? For example, could I use the plane detection to detect and put grass texture over an area and then drive a real RC car over it? Just like driving it on real grass.

I have tried out the plane detection on my iPhone 6s while what I found is when I tried to put anything from real world on the top of plane surface it just simply got covered by the plane. Could you please give me some clue if it is possible to make the plane just stay on the ground without covering the real world object?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's sth what you are searching for:
[ARKit hide objects behind walls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893320/arkit-hide-objects-behind-walls)

Or another way is i think to track the position of the real world object for example with apples [turicreate](https://github.com/apple/turicreate) or CoreML or both -> then don't draw your stuff on the affected position.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking moving objects is not supported, that's actually what it would be needed to make a real object interact with the a virtual one.

Said that I would recommend you using 2D image recognition and "read" every camera frame to detect the object while moving in the camera's view space. Look for the AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate protocol in Apple's developer site

Share your code and I could help with some ideas